# I have collection file provided by developer and I am getting response also in the Postman but its showing error for performance testing in Postman

Tags: postman, performance-testing

I have collection file provided by developer and I am getting response also in the Postman tool for functional test but its showing 100% error for performance testing in Postman tool for the same collection file. What could be the reason?